# PostgreSQL and python 3.7 string search

Tags: python, postgresql

I am a noob at this and appreciate all the help I can get.
Here goes:

I have a postgreSQL database that I would like to pull information out of and display the output.
I am using python 3.7 to do this.
I have connected to the database and can pull all the records and dump them on the screen.
When I try to do some logic checking, I run into problems.
Here is what I am attempting to do:

The database has two columns:
First Name and Last Name
I wanted to do a logic check, If your first name is John, print out the First and Last names.
For everyone else that is NOT named John, just print out the last name.

```
for row in test_database_1:
    if (row[0]=='John'):
        print ('Type:', row[0],':', row[1])
    else:
        print ('Type2:', row[0])
```

In the above statement, it completely skips the first print statement and just goes into the second one.

Let me know if you require additional clarification.

Thank you.

Comment: try to print the `row` before the `if else` statement to make sure that the name is the first column of the row (with `0` index)

Comment: I have already done that and confirmed that the value is correct.

Comment: "For everyone else that is NOT named John, just print out the last name". The last line suggests that the last name is the column with the `0` index. That is inconsistent with `if (row[0]=='John')`. Should it be `row[0]` or maybe `row[1]` index?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have done some debugging and saw something odd.
When the string in row[0] is returned, it is returned as 'John |with 16 spaces|'.
Because the field in the database is set to 20, row[0] returns the name + 16 blank spaces.
This, was quite an odd find.
Regardless. Once I figured out what the heck was happening with the string being returned from the database, I was able to resolve the issue in the following way:

```
for row in test_database_1:
if (row[0].strip()=='John'):
    print ('Type:', row[0],':', row[1])
else:
    print ('Type2:', row[0])
```